# how to add items to flip view dynamically?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a problem with adding Item to FlipView dynamically, I have a very simple FlipView and I put these codes in `SelectionChanged` event:

```
private void myFlipView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
    myFlipView.Items.Add(tb);
}
```

the strange is when I try to swipe between pages with mouse **rapidly** it works, but if I swipe with finger it stops working and I have to swipe on the page slowly to make it work.
I wish I could express the problem clearly....

Comment: You are going to need to refine your question if you want an answer. Maybe provide a little more source code so we can see?

Comment: there are no need to bring more source code[believe me], you can try this simple code as @user1954801 did, to find the problem....

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood correctly? What exactly do you want to achieve?

In your case you are adding a new `FlipViewItem` which contains a `TextBlock` every time you navigate throught the `FlipView`. So theoretically you will never reach the end of a `FlipView`.

Comment: It has no end because it supposed to be a calendar... I want to be able to navigate through the `FlipView` pages quickly, without any interruption, if you write these codes and run in the touch device you can see the interruption

Comment: I see. I just tested your code. It seems so that the problem on touch-devices is, that the SelectionChanged event gets fired after the sliding animation ended. So you have to wait until the animation is completed before you can slide to the next item.

You possibly have to rethink your program logic to avoid this problem. e.g. don't use the SelectionChanged event/load all FlipViewItems at once.